# How to discriminate among all the tickers associated with a single company?

Tags: stocks, etf, bonds, nasdaq, interactive-brokers

While following [Interactive Brokers (IBKR Mobile) Tutorial | From Zero to Hero](https://youtu.be/v0pRujcCjXU?list=PLNtoL6rfNKdmoHyOx4ft2q9L3ue1HjE8n&t=468) on my iPhone, I noticed there are many options linked to a company. In the screenshot we see, looking for Tesla will give more than 5 results.

[image]

As a beginner I have no idea which one should I buy. Any tips on how should I conduct the screening process?

No idea what's `NMS`, `LSEETF` or  `ETP`?

Comment: You simply do not want, what you don't understand! I guess the prefix LS stands for *Leverage Shares*. This is speculation, not investment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **NMS** is referring to the [National Market System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Market_System) - a standard market for equities trading in the U.S. For most people, this is the equity you'd want to trade in if you wanted to "own shares" of Tesla.
- **LSEETF** is likely referring to a *London Stock Exchange ETF*. In your screenshot, you've returned results specifically from [LeverageShares](https://leverageshares.com/en/), a specialized company that offers [ETF options that are designed specifically to apply "leverage" to magnify gains (and, consequentially, losses)](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/11637/investing-in-a-leveraged-index-etf-for-retirement-risky). These products are generally not great options for the average investor, especially if you don't understand the fundamentals behind this sort of strategy.

  As with all ETFs, investing in an instrument such as this gives you exposure to the price of Tesla's stock, but you aren't a direct owner of the shares and are instead a direct owner of shares of the ETF, which in turn owns the Tesla shares on your behalf.
- An **ETP** (Exchange-Traded Product) is a more broad term under which an *ETF* falls, but can also include things like **ETN**s, or Exchange-Traded Notes. (My understanding is that on the London Stock Exchange, this is more common terminology than using *ETF* or *ETN*, specifically.) ([Investopedia - ETP](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/e/exchange-traded-products-etp.asp))

> As a beginner I have no idea which one should I buy.

The rudimentary advice is to research ETFs that meet your investment goals, versus investing in individual companies. Beyond that, talk to a financial advisor.

Comment: Considering the paragraph "As with all ETFs, ..." why would one prefer one or the other if ETF is designed to win/lose accordingly to the stock behavior it refers to?

Comment: Where should I look for a financial advisor?

Comment: @ebepem Usually, an ETF will provide some advantage over investing in individual stocks. Most often, these are collections of equities in companies that are generally related to one another and managed by professionals. It’s a quick and easy way to get exposure to certain sectors, technologies, geographies that you may not think to or be able to practically invest in as an individual investor. Related: [What's an Exchange-Traded Fund (ETF)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/4/66846)

Comment: @ebepem I can’t help you with your second question - you may find useful advice in the other Money.SE thread: [How do I go about finding an honest & ethical financial advisor?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/70450/66846)